# Getting error creating a basic sql table

Tags: sql

Here is the code I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
ProductID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
Brand varchar (50) NOT NULL,
Price money NOT NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL,
DateAdded date NOT NULL
)
```

Here is what I'm trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO product
VALUE (100, 'Radio', 'Sony', 29.99, 30, '2012-08-22')
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
"Incorrect syntax near 'VALUE'."
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `VALUES` in you query,

```
INSERT INTO product 
VALUES (100, 'Radio', 'Sony', 29.99, 30, '2012-08-22')
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. I've spent, like, an hour on this. Thank you so much.  I will now proceed to shoot myself in the face.

Answer (score 1):

It's `VALUES` and not `VALUE`:

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (100, 'Radio', 'Sony', 29.99, 30, '2012-08-22')
```